# How to take values of joined tables with same column name?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, join

MainActivity.java:

```
    private void displayListView() {
    cursor = myDatabase.getJoinedInfo(etSearch.getText().toString());

    String[] columns = new String[] { myDatabase.RE_VALUE,
            myDatabase.GL_VALUE, myDatabase.KE_VALUE };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvHiragana, R.id.tvMeaning, R.id.tvKanji };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.wordonlist,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWordlist);
    // Assign adapter to ListView

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

MyDatabase.java:

```
public static final String GL_TABLE="gloss";
public static final String GL_ID="id";
public static final String GL_LANG="lang";
public static final String GL_VALUE="value";

public static final String KE_ID="id";
public static final String KE_VALUE="value";

public static final String RE_ID="id";
public static final String RE_VALUE="value";

public static final String LOG_TAG="myLogs";

public Cursor getJoinedInfo(String lookingFor)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: looking up info");

    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor;
    String query;

    query="SELECT " +
            " e.id AS _id," +
            " ke.id AS _id," +
            " ke.fk," +
            " ke.value," +
            " re.id AS _id," +
            " re.fk," +
            " re.value," +
            " s.id AS _id," +
            " s.fk," +
            " g.id AS _id," +
            " g.fk," +
            " g.lang," +
            " g.value" +
            " FROM entry e" +
            "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
            " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%' LIMIT 20";

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query = \n" + query.replace(", ",",\n  "));
    cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query complete");

    return cursor;      
}
```

I have 5 tables. 3 of them have column with name "value". Cursor is taking only one table's "value" and ignoring others. And all values which matches with search string, are similar! Please give some suggestion about how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: You found any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the `AS` keyword is to assign another name to a column, that is unique among all the retrieved columns. You're only using it on some of them, and always assign the same column name. The query should look like

```
query = "SELECT " +
        " e.id AS e_id," +
        " ke.id AS ke_id," +
        " ke.fk as ke_fk," +
        " ke.value as ke_value," +
        " re.id AS re_id," +
        " re.fk as re_fk," +
        " re.value as re_value," +
        " s.id AS s_id," +
        " s.fk as s_fk," +
        " g.id AS g_id," +
        " g.fk as g_fk," +
        " g.lang," +
        " g.value as g_lang" +
        " FROM entry e" +
        "     INNER JOIN k_ele ke ON e.id = ke.fk" +
        "     INNER JOIN r_ele re ON e.id = re.fk" +
        "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
        "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
        " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%' LIMIT 20";
```

That way, every column in the result set will have a different name. You should also improve your naming, because names like g, s,e, ke and re don't mean anything and make the code hard to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code did not work, but I understood  general meaning of AS and implemented. Can I ask one more question? How to avoid duplication of values in already joined table? For example, when I search "girl", it is giving 5 results because of duplication(it has 5 way of writing). How to make cursor give only one result? PS. You can see it in screenshot. One meaning, different writing(kanji)

Comment: Hi i have applied InnerJoin on 2 Tables 1 column that is primary key in First Table is foreign in the Second Table. Second table have 3 rows associated with the Foreign key i have managed to rawquery but don't know how to read the cursor let say having 1 row from first table and 3 rows from the second table in one query.